# How can I get fewer Techlog DataSelection events?

Tags: ocean, techlog

I wrote this test for DataSelection Event in my ternary plot in Techlog, and it gets too much data.

What am I doing wrong here?

In run method – subscribe to event:

```
void SetupTernaryPlot::run()
{
    workspace.connect(Workspace::SelectionChanged, this, SLOT(onSelectionChanged(const Slb::Techlog::SelectionChangedArgs&)));
}
```

This is my event handler:

```
void SetupTernaryPlot::onSelectionChanged(const Slb::Techlog::SelectionChangedArgs args)
{
    qWarning() << "TernaryPlot::onInteractiveSelectionChanged";
    int i=0;
    foreach (Selection selection, args.selectionsChanged())
    {
        qWarning() << "Interactive Selection " << i++ << selection.dataset().referenceVariable().rowCount() << endl; //selectlist;
    }
}
```

My event handler is getting too many points. How can I know what has been selected?

Comment: Thanks to Vipin for input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible to achieve this, even though the solution is not very elegant at this point.

If you study the "setuplogview" sample (SetupLogview::onSelectionChanged) in the package, you can find that you may use using -1 to filter out non-selected indices.

(If you have access to WAT, there is a ticket created to enhance this https://wat.grabels-fr0235.slb.com/techlog/ticket/24300)